# Replacing special characters with space

Tags: regex, abap

I have a description

> description with tab in it

ABAP converts this tab into # so its displayed as

> description with#tab in it

I want this to be replaced with SPACE so I am writing a check for valid characters and anything that is invalid is replaced with space.

I have the code below however it doesn't do the check for all the characters.

```
REPLACE ALL OCCURRENCES OF cl_abap_char_utilities=>horizontal_tab
    IN cs_orderadm_h_badi-description WITH ` `.
```

I have thought of using constant an writing out every valid character as a constant but i need a better way to do this.

Any help or advise is appreciated. Keep in mind that this is a conversion specific to SAP ABAP. Thanks

Comment: Does it need to be language dependent? Since a list of unprintable characters depends on the language and fonts used.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Looking for Non-Printable characters inside internal table ABAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675141/looking-for-non-printable-characters-inside-internal-table-abap)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
IF cs_orderadm_h_badi-description = gc_hex_char.
```

with

```
if cs_order_adm_h_badi-description CO gc_hex_char.
```

Answer (score 5):

Almost duplicate of [Looking for Non-Printable characters inside internal table ABAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675141/looking-for-non-printable-characters-inside-internal-table-abap)

```
REPLACE ALL OCCURRENCES OF REGEX '[^[:print:]]+$'
  IN cs_orderadm_h_badi-description WITH ''
  IGNORING CASE.
```

Comment: I would like to code it in a way so that it checks for valid characters and not invalid

Comment: Why ? You should want to check for invalid and replace those ?

Comment: I'm basically trying to make something like this work 


 **Constants:  gc_hex_char(66) VALUE 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890!"£$%^&*()_+=-[]{};@~#/.,<>?'.

  IF cs_orderadm_h_badi-description = gc_hex_char.
     
 ELSE.

    REPLACE ALL OCCURRENCES OF cl_abap_char_utilities=>horizontal_tab
      IN cs_orderadm_h_badi-description WITH ` `.

  endif.'**

Comment: So setting up the valid characters. If anything invalid is displayed it replaces with a space. But this doesnt work properly im missing something

Answer (score 1):

```
WRITE cs_orderadm_h_badi-description TO lw_hash_desc.
REPLACE ALL OCCURRENCES OF '#' IN lw_hash_desc WITH ` `.
cs_orderadm_h_badi-description = lw_hash_desc.
```

Will work for all special characters but will also replaces existing hashes. If you expect these in your strings you will first need to replace these with something unique and replace this with the hashes after the above code.