# Remove trailing hash'#' in tab delimited file-SAP ABAP

Tags: abap

I am reading a file from app server. It is a tab delimited file , I am trying to remove trailing hash(#) , But I am unable to do so.
I am using `split wa_string at cl_abap_char_utilities=>horizontal_tab` .

Even `CA` Contains Any does not seem to work.

```
LOOP AT ifile.

  CLEAR: wa_string.
  wa_string = ifile.
  SPLIT wa_string AT  cl_abap_char_utilities=>horizontal_tab
                      INTO  gt_load-werks
                            gt_load-edatv
                            gt_load-matnr
                            gt_load-qty.
  SHIFT gt_load-qty RIGHT DELETING TRAILING l_tab.

  IF gt_load-qty CA '#'.
    lv_len = strlen( gt_load-qty ).

    IF lv_len < 8 .
      lv_len1 = lv_len - 1.
      gt_load-qty = gt_load-qty+0(lv_len1).

      CONDENSE gt_load-qty.
    ENDIF.
  ENDIF.
ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Looking for Non-Printable characters inside internal table ABAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675141/looking-for-non-printable-characters-inside-internal-table-abap)

Comment: The question is, what is the last character?  A tab?  A carriage return?

Answer (score 3):

It is not '#' really. I think it is just placeholder for symbol with code 10 (0x0A) or 13 (0x0D). Look at qt_load-qty in hex mode in debugger.